# Product of a concave function and a decreasing function

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, functions

Let $f(x)$ and $g(x)$ be two positive continuous functions.
Function $f(x)$ is concave at $x_1$ and function $g(x)$ is $<1$ and is decreasing; $g(0)=1$ and $f(0)=0$.
Define function $h$ as the product of $f$ and $g$: $h(x)=f(x) g(x)$.

How can I prove (or disprove) that $h(x)$ increases from $0$ to reach a maximum at  $x_2\le x_1$, and then decreases for $x > x_2$ ?

What happens if we replace $g$ by $g_1$, such that $g_1(x)<g(x)$ ? do we get $x_3 < x_2$ ? Note that in this case $h(x)=f(x)g_1(x)$ reaches its maximum at $x_3$..

Comment: Are there assumptions, e.g. f and g are continuous/ differentiable?  Also, are we proving h *can* or *must* be concave?  Is it everywhere, or just at $x=x_1$?

Comment: Question edited.Thank you for your comment.

Comment: You still haven't addressed all my questions though...  Another one: g(x) decreasing everywhere, or just at $x=x_1$?

Comment: Thx again for your valuable comment!

Comment: $f$ is "concave": concave up or concave down?

Comment: $f$ is concave down

Answer (score 0):

Note: your $x_1$ is my $x$ (this is the way you initially stated the question).

Know: $f(x) > 0, g(x) > 0, f''(x)<0$, $g(x) < 1$, $g'(x) < 0$, $g(0) = 1$.

$h'(x) = f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x)$

$h''(x) = f(x)g''(x)+f'(x)g'(x)\cdot 2+f''(x)g(x)$

To get $h$ increasing from $0$ to $x_2\leq x$, and then decreasing, you need:

- $h'(x')>0$ iff $x' < x_2 \leq x$.  In particular,
- $f(x)g'(x)+f'(x)g(x) = h'(x) < 0$ implies: $f'(x) < \frac{-g'(x)\cdot f(x)}{g(x)}$, legitimate since $g(x)\geq 0$.
- $f(0)g'(0)+f'(0)g(0) = h'(0) > 0$ implies: $f'(0) > -g'(0)\cdot f(0) \geq 0$

Take any $f$ so that $f'(0)<0$.  Then the second condition will not hold, and so the function $h$ will not be increasing at 0, disproving your first part.

Since the function $h$ does not have to be in the form you provided, then the second part of your question is irrelevant.

The big picture is, you cannot infer the behaviour of a function on an interval, by knowing the behaviour of its constituents only at individual points.